# Number of reshuffles used to sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sequence, factorial

I found an interesting problem recently, which looks like this:

There is a dull **sorting algorithm** which takes the 1st number from an array, it finds an element which is lower by 1 than the 1st element (or it takes the highest element when there is no lower one), and puts it in the front. **Cost of putting element with index x (counting from 0) in the front is equal to its index.** It continues this process until the array is sorted. **The task is to count the cost of sorting all the n! permutations of numbers from 1 to n. The answer might be big so the answer should be modulo m (n and m are given in the input)**

**Example:**

```
Input (n,m): 3 40
Answer: 15

There are permutations of numbers from 1 to 3. The costs of sorting them are:
(1,2,3)->0
(1,3,2)->5
(2,1,3)->1
(2,3,1)->2
(3,1,2)->4
(3,2,1)->3
  sum = 15
```

My program generates all the possible arrays and sorts them one by one. Its complexity is O(n!*n^2), which is way too high. I am stuck with all my thoughts and this brute force solution.

**There are also some funny things I have discovered:**

1. When I have grouped the costs of sorting permutations by the quantity of those costs I am getting a strange figure:
   n=7
   https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/503942261051228160/905511062546292807/unknown.png
   (Each row has 2 numbers x * y, and y spaces before them. x-cost of sort, y-number of permutations(1-n) that have cost of sort equal to y). The score is all the rows x*y summed up. I can provide this figure for other n's, if needed.
2. It might be about fibonacci numbers, just a feeling.
3. As you can see the figure from the 1. has a segment in which all the y's are the same. It starts at x=n^2-4n+3.

### Question: How can I solve this problem more efficiently?

Comment: "Cost of putting element with index x (counting from 0) in the front is equal to its index." - it is the index in the original array (as opposed to the index in the current iteration), right?

Comment: It is the index in the current iteration. 4231, cost of next step here is 2, then we have 3421 and the next step also costs 2, not 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting algorithm has two phases: it first sorts the permutation
into some rotation of the identity and then rotates it to the identity.
We account for the cost of these phases separately.

The first phase consists of at most n−2 moves. After n−1−j moves, the
permutation consists of n−j values x, x+1, x+2, … mod n followed by a
permutation of the remaining j values that, assuming that we start from
a random permutation, are equally likely to be in any particular order.
The expected distance that we have to move x−1 mod n is ((n−j)+(n−1))/2.
But hang on, we only count the move if we’re still in the first phase.
Thus we need to discount the cases where the permutation is already a
rotation. There are n!/j! of them, and they all have x−1 at the end, so
the discount for each is n−1.

The second phase consists on average of (n−1)/2 moves from the end of
the permutation to the beginning, each costing n−1. The average cost
over all n! permutations is thus (n−1)²/2.

I’ll leave the modular arithmetic/strength reduction of the Python below
as an exercise.

```py
from itertools import permutations
from math import factorial


# Returns the total cost of sorting all n-element permutations.
def fast_total_sort_cost(n):
    cost = 0
    for j in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        cost += factorial(n) * ((n - j) + (n - 1)) // 2
        cost -= (factorial(n) // factorial(j)) * (n - 1)
    return cost + factorial(n) * (n - 1) ** 2 // 2


# Reference implementation and test.
def reference_total_sort_cost(n):
    return sum(sort_cost(perm) for perm in permutations(range(n)))


def sort_cost(perm):
    cost = 0
    perm = list(perm)
    while not is_sorted(perm):
        i = perm.index((perm[0] - 1) % len(perm))
        cost += i
        perm.insert(0, perm.pop(i))
    return cost


def is_sorted(perm):
    return all(perm[i - 1] <= perm[i] for i in range(1, len(perm)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for m in range(1, 9):
        print(fast_total_sort_cost(m), reference_total_sort_cost(m))
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Shifting to mod n, thinking in terms of rotations; there's so many subtleties.

Answer (score 1):

From the sorted permutation 123...n, you can build a tree using the reverse of the rule, and get all the permutations. See this tree for n=4.

[image: sorting_permutation]

Now, observe that

if node==1234 then cost(node) = 0

if node!=1234 then cost(node) = blue_label(node) + cost(parent)

What you need is to formulate the reverse rule to generate the tree.
Maybe use some memoization technique to avoid recomputing cost everytime.